# vim: copy into system clipboard not working

Tags: vim, yank

In my .vimrc I have those two lines for copy and paste into the system clipboard:

```
nnoremap <Leader>p "+p
nnoremap <Leader>y "+y
```

Weirdly the remapping of pasting works fine, but I can't copy any lines. If I press the buttons **"+y** it works and the highlighted text is in my system clipboard, but if I use **< Leader> y** it is only copied into a register inside vim, but not into the system clipboard.

Some help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your mapping in Visual mode, you have to use `vnoremap` or `noremap`, instead of `nnoremap` (which is for Normal mode only).

See `:h map-overview` for details.

Comment: Thanks, a quite obvious mistake, of course pasting works in normal mode, but if I highlight something I leave the normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your yanking mapping is incorrect. `"+y` lacks a motion. If you want to yank the whole line use upper Y (`"+Y`) or or yy (`"+yy`).

```
:help y
                        *y* *yank*
["x]y{motion}       Yank {motion} text [into register x].  When no
            characters are to be yanked (e.g., "y0" in column 1),
            this is an error when 'cpoptions' includes the 'E'
            flag.
```

Note that, if you type `"+y`, vim hangs in "operation-penging mode" (`:help Operator-pending-mode`).

Comment: You are right, thanks for the answer, but for me it was most important to copy highlighted code. My mistake was quite obvious :)

Comment: How to yank multilines(maybe 1, 2, 3,..., n lines)? such as we could use y2y, 3yy, y4y to copy 2, 3, 4 line to default register.